# Can I develop Android apps on Android?

Tags: android, c++, ide, clang

From this [web page](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html), it seems that, to develop C++ Android applications, a Windows, Linux or OS-X development platform is needed.

Is it possible to develop directly on an Android device?

Comment: You really want to develop an application on such a device? (even on a large tablet, I wouldn't want to... just for the missing keyboard)

Comment: Yes, with Aide IDE app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&hl=fr - but it's not totally free..

Comment: @xav - The idea is to use an immersive display such as [this one](http://www.atheerlabs.com/).

Comment: Whoo! To me, you're like Pierre Curie playing with radio-activity. Great things may come up, but you may also have some health issues ^^ Good luck @Pietro

Comment: @xav - Consider that the image is focused to infinity, so the eyes should not be stressed at all.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are planning on doing really SIMPLE things, you are probably better off doing it on a real computer of some sort. If nothing else because typing on a touch keyboard will drive you crazy in no time at all.

There are a few different tools that can be used on native Android systems, for example this one:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.n0n3m4.droidc
(It is not free, but not a huge amount either - and it's not clang, but it does C++ with the GCC compiler set).

If you want to develope GUI apps for Android, you are better of using Android's Java implementation. This http://code.google.com/p/java-ide-droid/ can probably do what you want in that respect. Again, you probably want a proper keyboard if you are doing more than a few play applicatins.

Comment: There are Android ports to machines with real keyboards and full size displays such as the Beagleboard, but the big problem is going to be finding suitable development tools compiled to run on Android.

Comment: Yes, but the term "Android device" does not sound like "Beagleboard with keyboard and screen" to me.